# Google App Engine - Django - Python - Ubuntu - Problems

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, python-2.7, ubuntu

I am reading 'Head First Python'. I am on Chapter 10 where Google App Engine is introduced. The initial hello world of using Python and Google App Engine was successful but subsequent programs have all failed.

I have the following **app.yaml** file:

```
application: three
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: page368b.py

libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.3"
```

With the following Python code (page368b.py):

```
import wsgiref.handlers

from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

#this line throws the error when accessing the web-page 
from google.appengine.ext.db import djangoforms

import birthDB

class BirthDetailsForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = birthDB.BirthDetails

class SimpleInput(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        html = template.render('templates/header.html', {'title': 'Provide your birth details'})
        html = html + template.render('templates/form_start.html', {})
        html = html + str(BirthDetailsForm(auto_id=False))     
        html = html + template.render('templates/form_end.html', {'sub_title': 'Submit Details'})
        html = html + template.render('templates/footer.html', {'links': ''})
        self.response.out.write(html)

def main():
    app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', SimpleInput)], debug=True)
    wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is another Python module imported into the one above called birthDB.py:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class BirthDetails(db.Model):
    name =          db.StringProperty()
    date_of_birth = db.DateProperty()
    time_of_birth = db.TimeProperty()
```

There is a **templates** folder that the above Python module calls. They have HTML code in them with some Django code. Here is an example using the **footer.html**.

```
<p>
{{ links }}
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The other HTML files are similar. I can start the Google App Engine with no problems using this command from BASH:  `python google_appengine/dev_appserver.py ~/Desktop/three` The directory **three** contains the **templates** folder, the **app.yaml** file, the Python modules shown above.

My problem is when I access the web-page at `http://localhost:8080` nothing is there and the BASH shell where the command is run to start this shows all the calls in the Python program that caused the problem and then finally says: **ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.**

I have read in a few different places a few different things to try so I thought I would go ahead and make a new post and hope that some expert Python programmers would chime in and lend their assistance to a lost hobbit such as myself.

Also, the book says to install Python2.5 to use this code but Google App Engine now supports Python2.7 that was not available as of the time of the books writing. Also, I just checked and Python2.5 is not even an option to use with Google App Engine. [Python2.5 deprecated](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/diff27)

This is probably too complex to solve on here. I am surprised all of these different technologies are used in a *Head First Python* book. It is asking a lot of a Python noob. ^_^

Regards,

user_loser

**UPDATE - I installed Django on my Ubuntu Operating System**

When I change the line in the python module 368b.py `from google.appengine.ext.db import djangoforms` to `from django import forms` I receive the following error on the console when accessing the web-page on `localhost`:

```
loser@loser-basic-box:~/Desktop$ google_appengine/dev_appserver.py three
INFO     2014-09-06 21:08:36,669 api_server.py:171] Starting API server at:       http://localhost:56044
INFO     2014-09-06 21:08:36,677 dispatcher.py:183] Starting module "default" running at:   http://localhost:8080
INFO     2014-09-06 21:08:36,678 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at:  http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2014-09-06 21:08:48,942 cgi.py:121] Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/loser/Desktop/three/page368b.py", line 13, in <module>
class BirthDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
File "/home/loser/Desktop/google_appengine/lib/django-1.3/django/forms/models.py", line  205, in __new__
opts.exclude, opts.widgets, formfield_callback)
File "/home/loser/Desktop/google_appengine/lib/django-1.3/django/forms/models.py", line 145, in fields_for_model
opts = model._meta
AttributeError: type object 'BirthDetails' has no attribute '_meta'

INFO     2014-09-06 21:08:48,953 module.py:652] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
ERROR    2014-09-06 21:08:49,031 cgi.py:121] Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/loser/Desktop/three/page368b.py", line 13, in <module>
class BirthDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
File "/home/loser/Desktop/google_appengine/lib/django-1.3/django/forms/models.py", line  205, in __new__
 opts.exclude, opts.widgets, formfield_callback)
 File "/home/loser/Desktop/google_appengine/lib/django-1.3/django/forms/models.py", line 145, in fields_for_model
opts = model._meta
 AttributeError: type object 'BirthDetails' has no attribute '_meta'
```

**Update Errors from running the program as is without making any changes:**

```
loser@loser-basic-box:~/Desktop$ google_appengine/dev_appserver.py  three/
INFO     2014-09-06 21:35:19,347 api_server.py:171] Starting API server at:   http://localhost:60503
INFO     2014-09-06 21:35:19,356 dispatcher.py:183] Starting module "default" running at:  http://localhost:8080
INFO     2014-09-06 21:35:19,358 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2014-09-06 21:35:25,011 cgi.py:121] Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/loser/Desktop/three/page368b.py", line 13, in <module>
class BirthDetailsForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
File "/home/loser/Desktop/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/djangoforms.py", line  772, in __new__
form_field = prop.get_form_field()
File "/home/loser/Desktop/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/djangoforms.py", line 370, in get_form_field
return super(DateProperty, self).get_form_field(**defaults)
File "/home/loser/Desktop/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/djangoforms.py", line 353, in get_form_field
return super(DateTimeProperty, self).get_form_field(**defaults)
File "/home/loser/Desktop/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/djangoforms.py", line 200, in get_form_field
return form_class(**defaults)
File "/home/loser/Desktop/google_appengine/lib/django-1.3/django/forms/fields.py", line 340, in __init__
super(DateField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/loser/Desktop/google_appengine/lib/django-1.3/django/forms/fields.py", line 99, in __init__
widget = widget()
File "/home/loser/Desktop/google_appengine/lib/django-1.3/django/forms/widgets.py", line 382, in __init__
self.format = formats.get_format('DATE_INPUT_FORMATS')[0]
File "/home/loser/Desktop/google_appengine/lib/django-1.3/django/utils/formats.py", line 67, in get_format
if use_l10n or (use_l10n is None and settings.USE_L10N):
File "/home/loser/Desktop/google_appengine/lib/django-1.3/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
self._setup()
File "/home/loser/Desktop/google_appengine/lib/django-1.3/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

Comment: Where did you place settings.py file?

Comment: Here is an example setup (not mine): http://django-rocket-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: @power there is no settings.py - Yes, I have read about this file but there was not one included in the example in the book. But the book was written when Python2.5 was still used in Google App Engine.

Comment: @power Interesting tutorial on rocket-engine... When installing Google App Engine it comes with Django 1.2-1.5. This is apparent when digging around in the folders: **google_appengine/lib/** With this in mind I do not think I need to install my own version of *django* on my machine. Plus, I need to stay inside the Google App Engine sandbox. Hi. 0_o

Comment: This file is generated by 'django-admin.py startproject' command. Please make sure you've run it correctly.

Comment: Just keep in mind - *Head First Python* was published in 2011, and a **lot** has changed since then, including the GAE API. I went through it fairly soon after it was published, and the instructions were pretty good then, but time passes...

Comment: @power How do I use the `django-admin.py startproject` command? Also, I just watched this awesome video that shows some programmer that uses django outside of GAE and they seem to work together. :D https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0C8IuokVBKQ

Comment: @MattDMo Thanks for the feedback. :D It is amazing how 3 years can date a book. There are a few typos in the book too, in addition to having some dated tutorials. All the other tuts worked so far though... I think it would of been more beneficial to focus on the standard library of Python but it is cool to learn some about cloud computing with GAE. Head First Books seem to be excellent introductions to languages. Still using Django, GAE, and Python together is pretty difficult especially for a noob. Head First Java and Head First MySQL/PHP never jumped into all these extra libraries and apps.

Comment: If you down-voted my initial question post please explain why as I think it is extremely detailed and has enough details to go on in order to lend some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're working with the example code that accompanies the book, available from this website: http://examples.oreilly.com/0636920003434/

If you download and expand the chapter 10 archive (`chapter10.zip`), you'll see several example files, and also several `.zip` archives.  The `page368b.py` file corresponds with the `webapp-chapter10-simpleform.zip` archive.  Open that archive to create a `webapp-chapter10-simpleform` directory.  This directory contains an `app.yaml` file, the `simpleform.py` file (identical to `page368b.py`), `birthDB.py` (an `ext.db` model class), and static and template file directories.

Unfortunately, as you may have already noticed, the example doesn't work out of the box with the latest SDK.  (I'm using version 1.9.10 of the SDK, which was just released.)  It reports "ImportError: No module named django.core.exceptions" when you attempt to load the page.  Strictly speaking, this example is *not* a Django application, but is merely trying to use a library that depends on Django being present.

The Python 2.5 runtime environment, which is selected by the `app.yaml` file included with this example, is meant to include Django 0.96 by default.  However, this behavior has changed in the SDK since *Head First Python* was written.  The smallest fix to get this example to work is to add these lines to `simpleform.py` prior to the import of `djangoforms`:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '0.96')
```

Then create a file named `settings.py` in your application root directory (the `webapp-chapter10-simpleform` directory).  This file can be empty in this case.  (As other commenters have noted, there is a better way to generate this file when using the Django framework, but in this case we just need the import to succeed.)

---

To upgrade this example to use the Python 2.7 runtime environment, modify `app.yaml` as follows:

```
application: simpleform
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /*.
  script: simpleform.app
```

The changes:

- `runtime:` is now `python27`
- `threadsafe: true` is added
- The reference to `simpleform.py` is now a Python object path to the global variable `app`.

Then modify `simpleform.py` so that everything following the definition of the `SimpleInput` class is replaced with:

```
app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', SimpleInput)], debug=True)
```

Instead of running the `simpleform.py` script, the Python 2.7 runtime environment imports it as a module, then looks for a WSGI application object in a global variable.  The lines we removed executed the app, and that's now done for us by the runtime environment.

From here, you can use a `libraries:` clause as you have done to select a newer version of Django, if you wish.  A quick test in a dev server shows that the modified example works with Django 1.5, which is the latest supported version.

Comment: Another aspect of this example that's a bit out of date is the use of the `ext.db` library.  If you'd like to go further with this once you've completed this chapter, you might want to look at the `ndb` library, also included with App Engine and described in the official App Engine docs.  There's no more built-in `djangoforms` support, though.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/

Comment: Also worth noting: The App Engine SDK will use its own version of Django, not the one you installed on your Ubuntu machine.  The SDK includes the supported versions of Django.  (I don't know whether this will be the case for future versions.)

Comment: Thank-you Dan for the help! This works on my machine. I now can see the form on page 369. You are quite the Python + Google App Engine magus. Also, can I work at Google like you? Thank-you again sir for answering the call to my Python coding bounty.:D